# Why won't my KeyPressed method run

Tags: java

I am trying to write a game in which a character moves around and jumps from block to block in order to get to the end. But the problem I'm facing is that my KeyPressed method won't run. I've tried putting a System.out.println("Hi"); in the method to see if it even starts running. But the "Hi" never showed up. This is my code.

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class Driver extends Applet implements KeyListener
{
    private int X = 0;
    private int Y = 250;
    private int sizeX = 25;
    private int sizeY = 25;
    private boolean start=false;
    public int  getX()
    {
        return X;
    }
    public void setX(int x)
    {
        X = x;
    }
    public int  getY()
    {
        return Y;
    }
    public void setY(int y)
    {
        Y = y;
    }
    public int  getsizeY()
    {
        return sizeY;
    }
    public void setsizeY(int sizey)
    {
        sizeY = sizey;
    }
    public int  getsizeX()
    {
        return sizeX;
    }
    public void setsizeX(int sizex)
    {
        sizeX = sizex;
    }
    public void init()
    {
        this.addKeyListener(this);
        setSize(300, 300);
        setFocusable(false);
        requestFocus();
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        init();
        map map1 = new map();
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 300);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        map1.paint(g);
        g.fillRect(X, Y, sizeX, sizeY);
        start=true;
    }
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
    {

    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
    {

    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
    {
        if(start)
        {
            System.out.println("Hi");
            if(e.getKeyChar() == 'w')
            {
                System.out.println("Hi");
                setY(getY()-1);
            }
            if(e.getKeyChar() == 'd')
            {
                setX(getX()+1); 
            }
            if(e.getKeyChar() == 'a')
            {
                setX(getX()-1);
            }
            if(e.getKeyChar() == 's')
            {
                setY(getY()+1);
            }
            repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

I am still learning how to code so please don't be mean, but if you could help that would be great!

Comment: Try putting that `System.out.println("Hi");` into the first line of the method. If yours looks like you posted it seems that `start` is never true and thus nothing happens.

Comment: what happens if you comment out `if(start)` in `keyPressed` method?

Comment: `map map1 = new map();` what map is this? the code wouldn't compile even